# TypeError: Cannot read property of 'id' of undefined

Tags: node.js

I am coding a discord.js Modmail Bot so whenever I run the "setup" command I get an error-
My code:-

```
const discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new discord.Client()
const { token, prefix, ServerID } = require("./config.json")

client.on("ready", () => {
console.log("I am ready to receive and Send Mails :D")


client.user.setActivity("Red Dragon")
})

client.on("channelDelete", (channel) => {
    if(channel.parentID == channel.guild.channels.cache.find((x) => x.name == "MODMAIL").id) {
        const person = channel.guild.members.cache.find((x) => x.id == channel.name)

        if(!person) return;

        let yembed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor("MAIL DELETED", client.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .setColor('RED')
        .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .setDescription("Your mail is deleted by moderator and if you have any problem with that than you can open mail again by sending message here.")
    return person.send(yembed)
    
    }


})


client.on("message", async message => {
  if(message.author.bot) return;

  let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
  let command = args.shift().toLowerCase();


  if(message.guild) {
      if(command == "setup") {
          if(!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
              return message.channel.send("You need Admin Permissions to setup the modmail system!")
          }

          if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
              return message.channel.send("Bot need Admin Permissions to setup the modmail system!")
          }


          let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find((x) => x.name == "SUPPORTER")
          let everyone = message.guild.roles.cache.find((x) => x.name == "@everyone")

          if(!role) {
              role = await message.guild.roles.create({
                  data: {
                      name: "SUPPORTER",
                      color: "GREEN"
                  },
                  reason: "Role needed for ModMail System"
              })
          }

          await message.guild.channels.create("MODMAIL", {
              type: "category",
              topic: "All the mail will be here :D",
              permissionOverwrites: [
                  {
                      id: role.id,
                      allow: ["VIEW_CHANNEL", "SEND_MESSAGES", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY"]
                  }, 
                  {
                      id: everyone.id,
                      deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL", "SEND_MESSAGES", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY"]
                  }
              ]
          })


          return message.channel.send("Setup is Completed :D")

      } else if(command == "close") {


        if(message.channel.parentID == message.guild.channels.cache.find((x) => x.name == "MODMAIL").id) {
            
            const person = message.guild.members.cache.get(message.channel.name)

            if(!person) {
                return message.channel.send("I am Unable to close the channel and this error is coming because probaly channel name is changed.")
            }

            await message.channel.delete()

            let yembed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor("MAIL CLOSED", client.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setColor("RED")
            .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setFooter("Mail is closed by " + message.author.username)
            if(args[0]) yembed.setDescription(args.join(" "))

            return person.send(yembed)

        }
      } else if(command == "open") {
          const category = message.guild.channels.cache.find((x) => x.name == "MODMAIL")

          if(!category) {
              return message.channel.send("Moderation system is not setuped in this server, use " + prefix + "setup")
          }

          if(!message.member.roles.cache.find((x) => x.name == "SUPPORTER")) {
              return message.channel.send("You need supporter role to use this command")
          }

          if(isNaN(args[0]) || !args.length) {
              return message.channel.send("Please Give the ID of the person")
          }

          const target = message.guild.members.cache.find((x) => x.id === args[0])

          if(!target) {
              return message.channel.send("Unable to find this person.")
          }


          const channel = await message.guild.channels.create(target.id, {
              type: "text",
            parent: category.id,
            topic: "Mail is Direct Opened by **" + message.author.username + "** to make contact with " + message.author.tag
          })

          let nembed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setAuthor("DETAILS", target.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
          .setColor("BLUE")
          .setThumbnail(target.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
          .setDescription(message.content)
          .addField("Name", target.user.username)
          .addField("Account Creation Date", target.user.createdAt)
          .addField("Direct Contact", "Yes(it means this mail is opened by a supporter)");

          channel.send(nembed)

          let uembed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setAuthor("DIRECT MAIL OPENED")
          .setColor("GREEN")
          .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
          .setDescription("You have been contacted by Supporter of **" + message.guild.name + "**, Please wait until he send another message to you!");
          
          
          target.send(uembed);

          let newEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setDescription("Opened The Mail: <#" + channel + ">")
          .setColor("GREEN");

          return message.channel.send(newEmbed);
      } else if(command == "help") {
          let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setAuthor('MODMAIL BOT', client.user.displayAvatarURL())
          .setColor("GREEN")
          
        .setDescription("This bot is made by patriotzest")
        .addField(prefix + "setup", "Setup the modmail system(This is not for multiple server.)", true)
  
        .addField(prefix + "open", 'Let you open the mail to contact anyone with his ID', true)
        .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
                    .addField(prefix + "close", "Close the mail in which you use this command.", true);

                    return message.channel.send(embed)
          
      }
  } 
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  if(message.channel.parentID) {

    const category = message.guild.channels.cache.find((x) => x.name == "MODMAIL")
    
    if(message.channel.parentID == category.id) {
        let member = message.guild.members.cache.get(message.channel.name)
    
        if(!member) return message.channel.send('Unable To Send Message')
    
        let lembed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("GREEN")
        .setFooter(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
        .setDescription(message.content)
    
        return member.send(lembed)
    }
    
    
      } 
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  if(!message.guild) {
      const guild = await client.guilds.cache.get(ServerID) || await client.guilds.fetch(ServerID).catch(m => {})
      if(!guild) return;
      const category = guild.channels.cache.find((x) => x.name == "MODMAIL")
      if(!category) return;
      const main = guild.channels.cache.find((x) => x.name == message.author.id)


      if(!main) {
          let mx = await guild.channels.create(message.author.id, {
              type: "text",
              parent: category.id,
              topic: "This mail is created for helping  **" + message.author.tag + " **"
          })

          let sembed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setAuthor("MAIN OPENED")
          .setColor("GREEN")
          .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
          .setDescription("Conversation is now started, you will be contacted by supporters soon :D")

          message.author.send(sembed)


          let eembed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setAuthor("DETAILS", message.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
          .setColor("BLUE")
          .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
          .setDescription(message.content)
          .addField("Name", message.author.username)
          .addField("Account Creation Date", message.author.createdAt)
          .addField("Direct Contact", "No(it means this mail is opened by person not a supporter)")


        return mx.send(eembed)
      }

      let xembed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("YELLOW")
      .setFooter(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
      .setDescription(message.content)


      main.send(xembed)

  } 
  
  
  
 
})


client.login(token)
```

The error I am getting is-
TypeError: Cannot Read property of 'id' of undefined

This code used to work earlier , would be grateful if you could help me it's somehow cannot getting the id. This code is written in javascript

Comment: 150 lines of code here, and you expect us to GUESS which of those lines get the error???

Comment: Sorry, i am getting error at line 37

Comment: Nope.  Line 37 of that snippet does not have the word "id" on it.  Really, you need to make it as easy as possible for us to help you.  Please show us the line of code that got the error.  Copy and paste it in the bottom of your question if you need to.

Comment: bruh i said from line 37

Comment: And bruh I said "nope".  The 37th line of the code you pasted above is blank.  Line 38 says `if(message.guild) {`.  If you can't take the time to show us what code failed, then don't expect any answers.